# ALPHA_THRESHOLD error?

Tags: android, alpha

I am getting as "ALPHA_THRESHOLD cannot be resolved or is not the field of ViewConfiguration"
and my code is as follows

```
// If the view has 0 alpha, we set it to be invisible so as to prevent
            // it from accepting touches
            if (alpha < ViewConfiguration.ALPHA_THRESHOLD) {
                v.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            } else if (v.getVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
                v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html), you can see the class `ViewConfiguration` doesn't have any accessible public constants.

If you read the source you can see that `ALPHA_THRESHOLD` is hidden (using `@hide` annotation).

```
/**
 * Minimum alpha required for a view to draw.
 * 
 * @hide
 */
public static final float ALPHA_THRESHOLD = 0.5f / PANEL_BIT_DEPTH;
```

Also `PANEL_BIT_DEPTH = 24`

I have no experience in what you are trying to do or if it's correct but you could replace your code with the following:

```
final static float ALPHA_THRESHOLD = 0.5f / 24;

if (alpha < ALPHA_THRESHOLD) {
   v.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
} else if (v.getVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
    v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```